# Multiple session id generated for different page of same website in PHP

Tags: php, session

PHP is unable to store the $_SESSION variable's value or indexes across the login page & the landing page. At first the problem was that with each page request a new SESSION ID was generated. But the even after that problem was solved it is unable to identify the $_SESSION variable's value or indexes.

**Login page Code**

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1)
{ 
    setcookie('user_id',$row['user_id'],time()+(60*60*24));
    setcookie('username',$row['username'],time()+(60*60*24));
    echo $row['user_id'];
    $name = $row['username'];
    if(!empty($_COOKIE['user_id'])&&!empty($_COOKIE['username']))
    header('Location: '."home.php",200);
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['username']= $name;
        header('Location: '."home.php",200);
    }
}
```

**Landing Page Code**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['PHPSESSID'])) {
    header('Location: '."index.php",200);
}
else{
   echo "Hello".$_SESSION["username"];
}
?>
```

**PHP.ini File Configuration**

session.use_cookies On  On

session.use_only_cookies    On  On

session.use_strict_mode Off Off

Comment: do you have `session_start()` on the login page as well?

Comment: make your `session_start();` Universal and call it with `include '';` why in login page your assign `$_SESSION['username']` to `$name`?

Comment: @andbeyond Yes session_start() is included in the login page too as  the first thing in the page.

Comment: @BrianS Well yea definitely I can call my `session_start()`; with `include '';` But the idea here is that if I do that I'll have to include the login validation with that, which I think will be an unnecessary overload on the login page(Since it actually is the login page, so whats the point of validating that on login page). Still if that can solve the problem then I am sure good with it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that every page has session_start() if you are using sessions.

If your example script, before you set the sessions user_id and name, call session_start().

Then on the landing page, check for 
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

Ideally, you should then check that the value for $_SESSION['user_id'] is in the correct format before redirecting.

---

FYI you should add die; on the line after your header() calls. You need to use die to stop execution of your script after header() in order to stop your script. Otherwise, your script will be executed till the end, what can cause some strange results.

Comment: Tried every thing suggested by you. Nothing worked :(